# How can I unnest list in column when calling pd.values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pd dataframe. When I call `pd.values`, the result is like:

```py
np.array([
    [1, 2, [0, 0, 0], 3],
    [1, 2, [0, 0, 0], 3]
])
```

and I want it to look like this when calling `pd.values`:

```py
np.array([
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3]
])
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please provide a sample of your `DataFrame` and try `pd.to_numpy()` instead of `pd.values`

Comment: Ummm.. where is your pandas dataframe

Comment: Typically, avoid storing lists in a `DataFrame`

Comment: my bad @Wen-Ben, the one provided by piRSquared below is a good sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, [0, 0, 0], 3],
    [1, 2, [0, 0, 0], 3]
])
```

I'd use the insight from [this post by @wim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641953/2336654) where I present the modified function below.

This flattens arbitrarily nested collections.

```
from collections import Iterable

def flatten(collection):
    for element in collection:
        if isinstance(element, Iterable) and not isinstance(element, str):
            yield from flatten(element)
        else:
            yield element
```

I can then use this to flatten each row of the dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame([*map(list, map(flatten, df.values))])

   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  1  2  0  0  0  3
1  1  2  0  0  0  3
```